# How to prevent Vim from jumping to first match when typing a search pattern?

Tags: vim

When I start to search some keywords by <kbd>/</kbd> in Vim, the cursor always move to the first match automatically when I input each character.

This behavior confuses me, so What can I do to disable it?

Answer (score 10):

You probably have `incsearch` set `on`.

You can set it off with `:set noincsearch`.

(Please, refer to `:help 'incsearch'` for more details.)

---

By the way, I want to give a personal suggestion: keep that option turned on.

Searching is a way of moving, but when `incsearch` is active, it's more versatile than any other movement because it gives you instant feedback of whether you're doing the movement you planned, and requires that you "confirm" the movement by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Just to give an example, see what happens if, with the cursor on (well, right before) the `h` in the following text, you hit <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>!</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
```

This is to say that <kbd>/</kbd> allows you to move to arbitrary places in the buffer and, via `incsearch`, it actually gives you feedback even before you actually commit to the move, thus allowing you to change the search pattern as you like, before hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Could you please explain what each part of that command does? It seems like it's deleting from 't' to the last 'ven', but in that case couldn't you just do `d/ve<C-g>Enter`?

Comment: @Dianne, that's what it does, yes (`\@<!` is a lookahead, see what it does in the doc ;)). But I didn't know about `<C-g>`, so thanks! By the way, I can't find the `:help` page for it. Can you link to it?

Comment: Ok, found, it's at `:help c_CTRL-G`.